# Split a dictionary if a value has more than two items in Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have the following list of dictionaries in Ansible:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "animal": "fox",
            "food": [
                "chickens"
            ]
        },
        {
            "animal": "rabbit",
            "food": [
                "carrots",
        "apples"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the second dictionary has two values for the "food" key. I want to split it in two and have it like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "animal": "fox",
            "food": [
                "chickens"
            ]
        },
        {
            "animal": "rabbit",
            "food": [
        "apples"
            ]
        },
        {
            "animal": "rabbit",
            "food": [
                "carrots"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately Im not able to come up with the logic. Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, use Jinja

```yaml
  final_list: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in animal_list|subelements('food') %}
    - { animal: {{ i.0.animal }}, food: {{ i.1 }} }
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  final_list:
  - animal: fox
    food: chickens
  - animal: rabbit
    food: carrots
  - animal: rabbit
    food: apples
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    animal_list:
      - animal: fox
        food: [chickens]
      - animal: rabbit
        food: [carrots, apples]

    final_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in animal_list|subelements('food') %}
      - {animal: {{ i.0.animal }}, food: {{ i.1 }}}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: final_list
```

---

- If there are more attributes in the dictionaries, for example,

```yaml
  animal_list:
    - animal: fox
      food: [chickens]
      pavilon: A
    - animal: rabbit
      food: [carrots, apples]
      pavilon: B
```

use the filter *combine*

```yaml
  final_list: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in animal_list|subelements('food') %}
    - {{ i.0|combine({'food': i.1 }) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by myself:

```
- name: Splitting the dictionaries if we have multiple values for a single key
  set_fact:
    final_list: "{{ final_list|default([]) + [{'animal': item.0.animal, 'food': item.1}] }}"
  loop: "{{ animal-list|subelements('food') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**